# Full column as default value in Pentaho Report Designer Parameter

Tags: parameters, pentaho, default-value, pentaho-report-designer

I have a column called 'EMPNAMES' which has not more than 20 names. I am using this column as a parameter in Pentaho Report Designer. I want to set all the 20 names as default value.

Instead of entering each and every record in the default value is there a way I can pass them directly using default value formula? The names in the column may increase or decrease with time, and hence I require a dynamic submission.

I don't really know, but this question may really seem silly to some of you. But still any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: If you still need help on this, Can you tell me do u want this parameter to be shown to the user or a hidden one? If shown, is it a drop down or a text box you use there? and do you use a ktr for this? I can help you on this.

Comment: Yes.. I want to show the drop down. But its just that when the report is first opened I need to display a set of data in the report as default. For Example: The SQL server column contains Employees:  A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H. Now there is a parameter called 'PM_Param' which must contain the values B,C,D,H as default values from the column Employees. So when I run the query which is something like 'SELECT * FROM EMPDATA WHERE Employees IN (${PM_Param})' it must first run for the default parameter values. I hope I am clear. Please feel free to ask if you did not understand the scenario.

Comment: Since it is a drop down, you want B,C,D,H all as one dropdown value. and others individually? Ex: "B,C,D,H" , "A" , "E", "F","G"  Furthermore  "B,C,D,H" value is the default selected value. Am I correct? I understand what your requirement is but cant understand how you want to present it to the user.

Comment: A little correction there, Marlon. I want everything - A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H in the drop down. But only "B,C,D,H" as default value. Also, this combination may change dynamically in the future based on a condition. Today the default value set is - "B,C,D,H" but some time later it may also change to "B,C,D,A,G,K". I hence wanted to set dynamic submission to the default values of the parameter.